# Multiple state version merge for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have a single state inside my React component which has the structure like this 
`{a: {x: 0}, b: {x:0}}`. During the operation time, i need to trigger several requests to server in order to request the data in order to update the state, and this need to be updated in the state. Since the number of the record in the database is quite big, I have to trigger several times

If I do like this

```
request_data(e) {
   ['a', 'b'].forEach((k) => {
      // do not mutate the state directly
      let new_state = _.extend({}, state);

      request(params, (err, res) => {
         // set result to the new_state 
         new_state = res; 
         // update the original state
         this.setState(newState);
      })
   });
}
```

inside the callback, the second request will not have the data of the first request the moment it request and update the origin state with the empty value for the first branch of the state structure.

One simple solution is updating the origin state directly, but I don't think it is a good idea. I am planning to integrate `redux` later but at this moment, since the current code base is quite big, migrating gradually is better. However, I dont' want to alter the origin state directly since it is not the `redux` way. Any suggestion to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Are you doing inside of a React component lifecycle method? Where does this code live?

Comment: I updating my app from Blaze to React at this moment and part of it still inside Blaze. The actual code is quite complicated involve the `ReactiveVar` of meteor as well, but assume that this code is inside a React Component. I don't see there is any different though since this is the general problem of merging multiple copies of the state during callbacks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by the way your code is written, you're using es6 classes for your component? That being the case, hopefully this tidbit will help:

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      foo:'bar'
    }
  }

  request_data = (e) => {
    ['a', 'b'].forEach((k) => {
      // do not mutate the state directly
      let new_state = _.extend({}, state);

      request(params, (err, res) => {
         // set result to the new_state 
         // update the original state
         this.setState(foo:res.foo)
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // component code here
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Notice that I'm using an arrow function for the request_data part...this is to avoid need to bind the function to the `this` variable inside of the constructor.

UPDATE:

I'm still not quite sure I understand what problem you're having here...but if you're not wanting to use redux right now, you could go with a container component method. Basically, your container component's main job is to manage the data and do nothing but pass its updated state to a child component as props. Something like this:

```
class MyComponentContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      a: {
        x: 0
      }, 
      b: {
        x:0
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     ['a', 'b'].forEach((k) => {
        request(params, (err, res) => {
           this.setState({
            a: res.a,
            b: res.b
           });
        })
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyComponent data={this.state} />
    )
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* display stuff here */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponentContainer
```

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I know that I can mutate the origin state directly, but i don't think it is a good idea. Since later, I might integrate with `redux` and i don't want to change my code again with the `immutablejs`

Comment: Using setState does not mutate the state directly. When you get to using redux, you will be able to create new state objects either with Object.assign or _.extend or with the spread operator as you please. In this case, you're inside of a component which gives you the setState method and does not mutate the state directly. It's a method that React components have exposed to update state.

Comment: if you're talking about this.state = {} in the constructor, that is not updating the state, but setting the initial value of it. We are talking about component state here, right?

Comment: Hi Mike, I m trying to use the `new_state` inside the function to put into `this.setState`. Imaging later I use `redux`, the code gonna be something like this in the reducers: `new_state = Object.assign({}, state); return new_state;`, and if my current code manage the `immutablejs` problem already, I dont need to think about the logic later

Comment: So you're wanting to mutate the state directly? In my opinion, I would still use redux here, since you're planning on using it in the future anyway, and just use redux for the React components you're migrating to. You can gradually create new reducers as necessary and you can use redux only on the components you need to. In other words, you can still use redux even if you're migrating gradually.

Comment: Thank Mike, but since the project is with Blaze as well, I don't want to overengineer the code.  Will spend more time on this. +1